# How to ensure only one job fires at a time in Quartz.NET?

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I have a Windows Service that uses Quartz.NET to execute jobs that are scheduled.  I only want it to pick up a single job at a time.  However, occasionally I am seeing behavior that indicates that it has picked up two jobs at once.

There are two log files (the regular one and one automatically generated when the regular one is in use) with jobs that start at the exact same time.  I can see both jobs executing in the QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS table, but only one has the correct instance ID, which is odd.

I have configured Quartz to use only a single thread.  Is this not how you tell it to only pick up a single job at a time?

Here is my quartz.config file with sensitive values hashed out:

```
quartz.scheduler.instanceName = DefaultQuartzJobScheduler
quartz.scheduler.instanceId = ######################
quartz.jobstore.clustered = true
quartz.jobstore.clusterCheckinInterval = 15000

quartz.threadPool.type = Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz
quartz.jobStore.useProperties = false
quartz.jobStore.type = Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz
quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType = Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.OracleDelegate, Quartz
quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type = Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.UpdateLockRowSemaphore, Quartz
quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000
quartz.jobStore.dataSource = default
quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString = ######################
quartz.dataSource.default.provider = OracleClient-20

#  Customizable values per Node 
quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 1
quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = Normal
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the threadcount = 1.

```xml
<add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="1"/>
<add key="quartz.threadPool.threadPriority" value="Normal"/>
```

(as you have done)

Make each of your jobs "Stateful"

```cs
[PersistJobDataAfterExecution]
[DisallowConcurrentExecution]
public class StatefulDoesNotRunConcurrentlyJob : IJob        /* : IStatefulJob */ /* Error  43  'Quartz.IStatefulJob' is obsolete: 'Use DisallowConcurrentExecutionAttribute and/or PersistJobDataAfterExecutionAttribute annotations instead. */
{
}
```

I've left in the name of the ~~older~~ version of how to do this (namely, the "IStatefulJob") and the error message that is generated when you code to the outdated "IStatefulJob" interface.  But the error message gives the hint.

Basically, if you have 1 thread AND every job is marked with "DisallowConcurrentExecution", it should result in 1 job at any given time..running in "serial mode".

Comment: I am using an older version of Quartz, so I had tried the IStatefulJob approach, but it was allowing multiple jobs to execute.  It seems that in Quartz, there is a distinction between jobs and job types.  These are all the same job type, but different jobs.  I would be willing to upgrade to a newer version of Quartz to use the DisallowConcurrentExecution attribute if it will guarantee serial execution...

Comment: I did a POC one time, and showed a single job running on one thread.  I would suggest doing a small Proof Of Concept...with the new version before wholesaling upgrading.  But I would think there was some kind of issue with IStatefulJob...since they changed from interface to [Attribute].  My simple job popped a textfile in the .temp directory.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm in the process of doing now.  Will post something when I have results.